# Parsing Tab Delimited File into an array

Tags: perl

I am attempting to read a CSV into an array in a way that I can access each column in a row. However when I run the following code with the goal of printing a specific column from each row, it only outputs empty lines.

```
#set command line arguments
my ($infi, $outdir, $idcol) = @ARGV;

#lead file of data to get annotations for
open FILE, "<", $infi or die "Can't read file '$infi' [$!]\n";
my @data;
foreach my $row (<FILE>){
    chomp $row;
    my @cells = split /\t/, $row;
    push @data, @cells;
}


#fetch genes
foreach (@data){
    print "@_[$idcol]\n";
#    print $geneadaptor->fetch_by_dbID($_[$idcol]);
}
```

With a test input of

```
a       b       c
1       2       3
d       e       f
4       5       6
```

I think the issue here isn't so much loading the file, but in treating the resulting array. How should I be approaching this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using a hash instead of an array?

Comment: Would a hash be equivalent to a python dictionary? If so, then yeah it'd make more sense to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to avoid parsing the CSV file directly and using the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module.

```
use Text::CSV;
use Carp;

#set command line arguments
my ($infi, $outdir, $idcol) = @ARGV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
  sep_char => "\t"
});

open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $infi) || croak "can't open $infi: $!";

# Uncomment if you need to skip header line
# <$fh>;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        my @columns = $csv->fields();
        print "$columns[0]\t$columns[1]\t$columns[2]\n";
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: The [text/tab-separated-values MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values) is defined very simply so that data cannot contain the tab character. There is no quote or escape character, so the correct way to parse tab-separated data is with a simple `split /\t/`. To set up `Text::CSV` correctly you also have to suppress `quote_char` and `escape_char` and it should end up just splitting on tabs, and the module loses all of its value.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but the questioner said "I am attempting to read a CSV", so I can't assume the file doesn't include quotes or escape character...

Comment: That was clearly a misconception as a CSV is, by definition, comma-separated.

Comment: Sorry about that mix up. I am parsing gene annotation which has quote characters due to the annotations being packed with every character and delimiter under the sun. I mixed up CSV and TSV because the files I have come to me in either form. I was unaware that TSV didn't allow for such characters as I've always found them, but then again biologists make these files...

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to `push @data, \@cells`, otherwise you will get all the fields concatenated into a single list.

Then you need to use the loop value in the second `for` loop.

```
foreach (@data){
    print $_->[$idcol], "\n";
}
```

`@_` is a completely different variable from `$_` and is unpopulated here.

You should also consider using

```
while (my $row = <FILE>) { ... }
```

to read your file. It reads only a single line at a time whereas `for` will read the entire file into a list of lines before iterating over it.